# Problem with python code

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4

Can someone look at this script and see what the problem is?  It used to work with arcgis 10.3 but now I can't get it to work with 10.4 on a different computer.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Data and Maps\2014MDCExport_CountyWide_localData.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Grid")[0]  ##shapefile layer name called grid
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr)
x=1
for row in rows:
    df.extent = row.Shape.extent
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\GIS\OC Sheriffs\Image\L2\ " + str(row.getValue("PageName")) + ".jpg", df, df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 1200, resolution = 96, world_file=True, jpeg_quality = 100)
    print x
    x+=1
del mxd
```

Error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1026, in ExportToJPEG
    layout.exportToJPEG(*args)
AttributeError: DataFrameObject: Error in executing ExportToJPEG
```

Comment: `C:\GIS\Data and Maps\2014MDCExport_CountyWide_localData.mxd` Is the path to your data correct? Can this other computer access the MXD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message occurs when your output folder doesn't exist.  Check that `C:\GIS\OC Sheriffs\Image\L2` exists on the different computer you are now running the script on.  You can use `os.path.isdir()` to test whether a folder exists.

```
outputFolder = r"C:\GIS\OC Sheriffs\Image\L2" # Your Output folder path to store the exported JPG files
# Check that the path exists
if os.path.isdir(outputFolder):
    ## the rest of your code goes here
else:
    print "The folder doesn't exist!"
```

Since you're running ArcGIS 10.4 I would migrate the script from the old `arcpy.SearchCursor()` to the more efficient `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`

```
import arcpy, os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Data and Maps\2014MDCExport_CountyWide_localData.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Grid")[0]  

outputFolder = r"C:\GIS\OC Sheriffs\Image\L2" # Your Output folder path to store the exported JPG files

# Check that the path exists
if os.path.isdir(outputFolder):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['PageName', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            df.extent = row[1].extent
            outputFilePath = r"{}\{}.jpg".format(outputFolder, row[0])
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outputFilePath, df, df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 1200, resolution = 96, world_file=True, jpeg_quality = 100)
else:
    print "Folder {} doesn't exist!".format(outputFolder)
```

---

Have updated the script to add a extent buffer to add a bit of space around the current feature.  This increases the extent scale by a specified percentage, then rounds that scale up to the next value that matches specified rounding factor (explained below the script)

```
import arcpy, os
def update_scale(df, extraScalePct, scaleRound):
    exScale = df.scale # Current scale
    newScale = exScale + (exScale * (float(1)/(float(100)/extraScalePct)))  # Increase DF scale by specified amount
    roundScale = (newScale + (scaleRound -1)) // scaleRound * scaleRound # Round the new scale up to the next value as specified
    return roundScale

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Data and Maps\2014MDCExport_CountyWide_localData.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Lines")[0]  ##shapefile layer name called grid

outputFolder = r"C:\GIS\OC Sheriffs\Image\L2" # Your Output folder path to store the exported JPG files
if os.path.isdir(outputFolder):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['PageName', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print row[0]
            df.extent = row[1].extent
            df.scale = update_scale(df, 10, 250) # Increase scale by 10% then round up to next 250
            outputFilePath = r"{}\{}.jpg".format(outputFolder, row[0])
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outputFilePath, df, df_export_width = 1200, df_export_height = 1200, resolution = 96, world_file=True, jpeg_quality = 100)
else:
    print "Folder {} doesn't exist!".format(outputFolder)
```

To set the extent buffer and the rounding, modify the line `df.scale = update_scale(df, 10, 250)`.  `df` is your dataframe, `10` is the percentage to increase the scale (e.g. 1:250 becomes 1:275), `250` is the rounding factor that the new scale is rounded up to (e.g. 1:275 becomes 1:500).  Modify these two values to suit.

Comment: Also,  I wanted to export a small amount of data around the polygon.  Right now it cuts the data right to the polygon.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Mark I have added some code that will allow you to add extra space after zooming to each feature.